# Javascript class method vs prototype property

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, for-in-loop

[for-in example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBafz.png)

http://jsbin.com/mosedibera/edit?js,console

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
}

Point.prototype.point = function() {
  console.log('point')
}

var point = new Point(1, 2)
for (var x in point) {
  console.log(x)  // x y point
}
console.log(point)

class ClassPoint {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
  point() {
    console.log('class point')
  }
}
var classPoint = new ClassPoint(1, 2)
for (var y in classPoint) {
  console.log(y) // x y (without point)
}
console.log(classPoint)
```

As the image show, I am curious the difference between ES2015 class and prototype.
The result of for-in is different. (Although use Object.hasOwnProperty() can avoid the issue)

Does anyone know the reason made the for-in result?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Include **code**, not *pictures* of code.

Comment: Please either add the fiddle link or post the code. No one will type the code for you.

Comment: @guyfawkes: Posting a fiddle link without code is not allowed. Also completely unnecessary in this case, we have Stack Snippets for runnable examples.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's correct +1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for your feedbacks. I've added the code and jsbin link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in `for-in` is because `class` syntax automatically makes the methods *non-enumerable*, whereas when you do:

```
Point.prototype.point = function() {
  console.log('point')
}
```

...that creates an *enumerable* property on the object used as the prototype of objects created by that constructor function.

You could do the same thing `class` does via `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Point.prototype, "point", {
    value: function() {
        console.log('point')
    },
    writable: true
});
```

That creates a non-enumerable property instead of an enumerable one (because we haven't included `enumerable: true` and the default is `false`; we also haven't included `configurable: true` and so the property isn't configurable, which is also what `class` does with methods).

Live example:

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
}

Object.defineProperty(Point.prototype, "point", {
    value: function() {
        console.log('point')
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

var point = new Point(1, 2)
for (var x in point) {
  console.log(x)  // x y point
}
console.log(point)

class ClassPoint {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
  point() {
    console.log('class point')
  }
}
var classPoint = new ClassPoint(1, 2)
for (var y in classPoint) {
  console.log(y) // x y (without point)
}
console.log(classPoint)
```

---

There are other minor differences related to `super`, but that's not related to your `for-in` question, and as you're not using `super` in that code, they don't come into it anyway.